# java util list as jquery ajax response on spring mvc

Tags: scala, jquery, spring-mvc

**Controller**

```
 @RequestMapping(value = Array("getPatternId.html"), method = Array(RequestMethod.GET))
      @ResponseBody def getPattern(model:ModelMap,@RequestParam patternId: Long):List[Question] = {


         var list: List[Question] = questionService.findQuestionByQuestionPattern(patternId)
        var questions: java.util.List[Question] = ListBuffer(list: _*)
     questions
      }
```

**script**

```
 function getPattern(id) {

            $.ajax({
                type : 'GET',
                url : " /learnware/getPatternId.html ",

                data : ({
                    patternId : id
                }),
                success : function(response) {

                    // we have the response

                    $('#info').html(response);
                },
                error : function(e) {

                    alert('Error: ' + e);

                }
            });

        }
```

When i send response as string it  display it on html page 
but when i return a list it does no show the data

```
<div id="info" style="color:green;"></div>
```

current response will be add to div witn id info

Comment: Put jackson on the classpath. Spring will detect it and configure message converters to convert objects to JSON.

Comment: json is not useful..i need to parse list to page

Comment: when i convert my list to json by " new JSONArray(list).toString()"
it gives me full list of data in json